# What is the Negative sentence of "All good things come to an end"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, antonyms

What is the Negative sentence of "All good things come to an end" ?? Like what would be its antonym and why ??

Comment: Negatives and Antonyms are two different things. Hence it will be quite unclear in this case.

Comment: Are you able to do an antonym for this one ??

Comment: The [definition of antonym](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antonym) is "**a word** of opposite meaning" - that is, it only applies to a single word (i.e., "bad" is an antonym of "good"). You can't have an antonym of an entire sentence.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the OP wants the "negation" of the sentence.  But doesn't know the technical term.  We don't insist that learners know all the technical words in English before asking a question!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat this as a problem in logic then:

> It is not the case that all good things come to an end.

But we can logically simplify that:

> Some good things don't come to an end.

or, interpreting slightly:

> Some good things last forever.

<sub>(In formal logic, where "P(x)" is any unquantified statement with a variable x,  "¬∀x P(x)" is equivalent to "∃x ¬p(x)" )</sub>

Comment: Was it necessary to mention the formula of mathematical logic? There is nothing wrong, just asking for my own satisfaction.

Comment: Totally unnecessary.  I put it in a (sub) to say this is not really part of the answer.  The logical process here is not unique to English.  Indeed, I think every language that has negations and universal/existance quantifiers (ie every human language?) has the same rule.